# Reading JSON Output

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio

I am using **VB.net** in Visual Studios. And for the past day I have been struggling to deserialize and read a JSON output which is returned from an API I am using. I believe I am struggling mostly due to not understanding what output this is (I believe it  is a collection of JSON arrays as opposed to an output of just one array).
Here is the output I receive:

```
    [{
    "Issue": {
        "ID": 80,
        "Name": "Cold",
        "Accuracy": 90,
        "Icd": "J00",
        "IcdName": "Acute nasopharyngitis [common cold]",
        "ProfName": "Common cold",
        "Ranking": 1
    },
    "Specialisation": [{
        "ID": 15,
        "Name": "General practice",
        "SpecialistID": 3
    }]
}, {
    "Issue": {
        "ID": 11,
        "Name": "Flu",
        "Accuracy": 65.390625,
        "Icd": "J10;J11",
        "IcdName": "Influenza due to other identified influenza virus;Influenza, virus not identified",
        "ProfName": "Influenza",
        "Ranking": 2
    },
    "Specialisation": [{
        "ID": 15,
        "Name": "General practice",
        "SpecialistID": 3
    }, {
        "ID": 19,
        "Name": "Internal medicine",
        "SpecialistID": 4
    }]
}, {
    "Issue": {
        "ID": 83,
        "Name": "Inflammation of the brain covering membranes",
        "Accuracy": 45.4921875,
        "Icd": "G00;G01;G02;G03",
        "IcdName": "Bacterial meningitis, not elsewhere classified;Meningitis in bacterial diseases classified elsewhere;Meningitis in other infectious and parasitic diseases classified elsewhere;Meningitis due to other and unspecified causes",
        "ProfName": "Meningitis",
        "Ranking": 3
    },
    "Specialisation": [{
        "ID": 15,
        "Name": "General practice",
        "SpecialistID": 3
    }, {
        "ID": 23,
        "Name": "Infectiology",
        "SpecialistID": 28
    }, {
        "ID": 19,
        "Name": "Internal medicine",
        "SpecialistID": 4
    }, {
        "ID": 27,
        "Name": "Neurology",
        "SpecialistID": 45
    }]
}]
```

If someone could help me understand the structure I have here, and how to go about cleanly dissecting this into query-able information. I would be greatly appreciative. 
I have tried following along many of the similar questions here and on other sites, but am failing to implement any of the code and getting errors relating to incorrectly defining arrays or objects.
I am also using Newtonsoft.json

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
        For Each item As JProperty In data
        item.CreateReader()
        Select Case item.Name
            Case "Issue"
                output += "Issue:" + vbCrLf
                For Each comment As JObject In item.Values
                    Dim u As String = comment("ID")
                    Dim d As String = comment("Name")
                    Dim c As String = comment("Accuracy")
                    output += u + vbTab + d + vbTab + c + vbCrLf
                Next

            Case "Specialisation"
                output += "Specialisation:" + vbCrLf
                For Each msg As JObject In item.Values
                    Dim f As String = msg("ID")
                    Dim t As String = msg("Name")
                    Dim d As String = msg("SpecialistID")
                    output += f + vbTab + t + vbTab + d + vbTab
                Next

        End Select
    Next
    MsgBox(output)
```

I receive the error:

```
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Additional text encountered after 
finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 216.'
```

Comment: This should get you going:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46669032/vb-net-how-to-read-the-json-response-on-http/46671843#46671843

Comment: Your error message says, *'Additional text encountered after 
finished reading JSON content: ,. Path '', line 1, position 216.'* -- but your JSON has 62 lines.  Can you [edit] your question to provide a [mcve] that actually demonstrates the exception -- a console app we can compile, run, and test?  You might also check out [ask] and take the [tour] as both give suggestions on how to *Help others reproduce the problem*.

Comment: Position 216 is referring to the position in the string and not the line. I believe it is reading the JSON output as a single line, meaning the error it's referring to is after the first "Issue" with }, {. I believe the error is related to the application not expecting the start of a second "Issue" after the first one is complete.
The provided code is as MCV as it gets. Unfortunately I cannot make a console app. As stated, it uses an API. The code posted is everything on how I am processing my JSON (where i am having trouble) I need guidance on a way to process multiple { "Issue": } arrays.

Comment: I uploaded your JSON to https://jsonlint.com/ and it was successfully parsed with no errors.  Is the JSON in your question the actual JSON you are receiving or did you edit it for the question?  *Unfortunately I cannot make a console app.* - I think you could if you just embed the returned JSON as a string literal.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/4OlUXU for an example.

Comment: It's the actual full JSON that is given from the API. I think the issue is that the code I am using to parse it will only be successful for one of the  [{
    "Issue": { ...  }, "Specialisation": [{ ... }] },
As soon as it hits the comma to go to the next Issue, it errors. Not sure how I can iterate this properly for each Issue

Comment: Your error is a [`JsonReaderException`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonReaderException.htm).  Json.NET throws that error when it is reading JSON text and encounters invalid syntax.  It throws a different error if your code does something wrong in processing the results afterwards.  But the JSON in your question parses perfectly, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/ACrAwK.  Can you fork the linked fiddle and modify it so it fails in the way you are seeing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is how I solved my issue:**
The issue lied with the way I was Deserializing my object. I failed to recognize how to handle a JSON array vs the JSON Object vs a JSON Attribute

```
Public Function GetIllness()
response = <Insert API Query with header>.asJsonAsync(Of String)()
        Dim client = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of RootClass)(response.Result.Body)
        MsgBox(client.DescriptionShort)
        MsgBox(client.TreatmentDescription)
 End Function

<Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObjectAttribute(MemberSerialization:=Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)>
    Partial Public Class RootClass

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Issue As Issue

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Specialisation() As Specialisation

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Description As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public DescriptionShort As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public MedicalCondition As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Name As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public PossibleSymptoms As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public ProfName As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Synonyms As Object

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public TreatmentDescription As String
    End Class

    'Type created for JSON at <<root>>
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObjectAttribute(MemberSerialization:=Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)>
    Partial Public Class Issue

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public ID As Integer

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Name As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Accuracy As Double

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Icd As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public IcdName As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public ProfName As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Ranking As Integer
    End Class

    'Type created for JSON at <<root>> --> Specialisation
    <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonObjectAttribute(MemberSerialization:=Newtonsoft.Json.MemberSerialization.OptIn)>
    Partial Public Class Specialisation

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public ID As Integer

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public Name As String

        <Newtonsoft.Json.JsonPropertyAttribute()>
        Public SpecialistID As Integer
    End Class
```